# Kubernetes ingress-nginx fails when accessing the host from within the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

I've got a problem with ingress-nginx. Which is working if I access the host publicly. However, accessing the host from within the cluster seems to fail.
PS: I installed nginx-ingress as DigitalOcean one-click install suggestion. But I don't think the problem has in DO. I've been trying find and solve this issue for last 3 days.

```
2021/04/19 07:40:28 [error] 887#887: *2244049 broken header: "���'V�����Y%��i�����:U��Ta�fv�n
                                                                                              mg
                                                                                                {>3�����B� �ջ��+Mw���hc��ސZ�,�+�0��.�2���/��-�1�" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 10.244.3.30, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/04/19 07:40:28 [error] 887#887: *2244050 broken header: "������b���Tڒ�1��w0���zF�A<� �e�USs!��l�JOca�"�� *)�˄Z�,�+�0��.�2���/��-�1�" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 10.244.3.30, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I tested it by SSLPoke, got same result. This is testing it within as cluster.
[image]

the result from curl in pod (within cluster), but when i check it publicly it's working right:

[image]

the configuration in digitalocean loadbalancer

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: I did, sorry to hear it. I followed this:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3996#issuecomment-566460867

Comment: @yondkoo The recommended approach on S.O. is to add your own answer and accept it. It will help others to go that.

Comment: I answered it but @Samuel Liew (i assume he is the S.O. moderator) deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the cluster you should use pure http without SSL.

SSL is used only from "outside"

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) There was some policy that I had to follow (use SSL in the cluster) at that time.
I spent 4 days figuring it out. I assume it was DigitalOcean's issue.